# How to solve Call to a member function notify() on array? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail, laravel-5.3

My listener is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\CheckoutOrderEvent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Mail;

class CheckoutOrderListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function handle(CheckoutOrderEvent $event)
    {
        // dd($event);
        $event->data->notify(New \App\Notifications\CheckoutOrder($event->data));
    }
}
```

If I run dd($event), the result is like this :

[image]

When executed, there exist error : Call to a member function notify() on array

How to solve it?

Comment: Arrays do not have methods (member functions)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`notify()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications) on a model with `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait, but definitely not on an array.

For example, you can get an instance of a `User` first:

```
$user = User::where('email', $event->data['email'])->first();
```

And then use `notify()`:

```
$user->notify(....)
```

Comment: There exist error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()`

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627259/how-to-solve-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-buildernotify

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was trying to send email to end-user of the application for activating their account (Provided in registration form ) then i got this Error because i was passing "ID" to notify(), actually it should pass whole details of users.
[image]

Solved By changing in Http/Controller/Admin/Auth/RegistrationController.php

[image]

And that's my Notification Class: app/Notification/UserActivate.php Look at my

`__construct() and toMail($notifiable) methods`

[image]

I hope my mistake helped you. :)