# How to solve Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail, laravel-5.3

My function create in controller is like this :

```
public function create()
{ 
    // This is dummpy data to testing checkout order event
    $data = array(
                'number'            => '2', 
                'user'              => 'chelsea',
                'store'             => 'chelsea shop', 
                'total_amount'      => 11000000, 
                'total_product'     => 2,
                'status'            => '92000000', 
                'delivery_address'  => 'london',
                'email'             => 'chelsea@gmail.com'
            );
    $data = Order::where('number', $data['number'])->first();
    \Event::fire(new CheckoutOrderEvent($data));
}
```

My CheckoutOrderListener is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;
use App\Events\CheckoutOrderEvent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
class CheckoutOrderListener
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(CheckoutOrderEvent $event)
    {
        $event->data->notify(New \App\Notifications\CheckoutOrder());
    }
}
```

I had add use `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;` in model order

But, when executed, there exist error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()`

Is there anyone can help me?

**Update**

The full error is like this :

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2440: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()

    in Builder.php line 2440
    at Builder->__call('notify', array(object(CheckoutOrder)))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'notify'), array(object(CheckoutOrder))) in Builder.php line 1438
    at Builder->__call('notify', array(object(CheckoutOrder)))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'notify'), array(object(CheckoutOrder))) in compiled.php line 11602
    at Model->__call('notify', array(object(CheckoutOrder))) in CheckoutOrderListener.php line 33
    at CheckoutOrderListener->handle(object(CheckoutOrderEvent))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckoutOrderListener), 'handle'), array(object(CheckoutOrderEvent))) in compiled.php line 10127
    at Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(object(CheckoutOrderEvent))
    at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(CheckoutOrderEvent))) in compiled.php line 10067
    at Dispatcher->fire('App\Events\CheckoutOrderEvent') in compiled.php line 6290
    at Facade::__callStatic('fire', array(object(CheckoutOrderEvent))) in OrderController.php line 68
    at OrderController->create()
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(OrderController), 'create'), array()) in compiled.php line 9385
    at Controller->callAction('create', array()) in compiled.php line 9412
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(OrderController), 'create') in compiled.php line 8470
    at Route->runController() in compiled.php line 8451
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8147
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9978
    at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3151
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13467
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11907
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13213
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13150
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9855
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8148
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8139
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8130
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2472
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3213
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9870
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9855
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2416
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2400
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

My CheckoutOrderEvent is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Events;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class CheckoutOrderEvent
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

My CheckoutOrder is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
class CheckoutOrder extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

My model order is like this :

```
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Order extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
..........
```

Comment: Can you also paste us the whole error stack? The evidences here doesn't really tells us where is the issue. It seems like the event's `$data` property is still a query builder - which in your `store`, you did called `->first()` to get model.

Comment: @Lionel Chan, I had update my question

Comment: How about showing your `App\Event\CheckoutOrderEvent` class

Comment: @Lionel Chan, I had update my question

Comment: It's weird that the code you shown and the errors doesn't tally. The code clearly says that you passed `Order` model into the event, but in your error stack, it says it's trying to call `notify` on an object (probably model) called `CheckoutOrder`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your error stack is showing codes runs in `OrdersController->create`, not `store`. Can you show your code in `OrdersController->create`?

Comment: @Lionel Chan, I'm sorry, my method is should create. not  store. I update my question. I add `checkoutOrder` too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133047/discussion-between-lionel-chan-and-moses-toh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from the discussion I found out that you did not include the `Notifiable` trait in your `Order` model. Do this instead:

```
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Order extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, Notifiable;
    ..........
```

By including it, your model should now have the `notify` method as it should, and so can be used in the Notification system.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error while put a query like

```
$data = DB::abcd("Select * from xyz"); ,(abcd->filename)
```

but we need to put

```
$data = DB::select("Select * from xyz");
```